# How can I bind and sort a collection

Tags: wpf, data-binding

If I have an unsorted collection, is there an easy way to bind and sort it. I would like to do it in XAML (no Linq, no C#)

If my DataContext has a property, say, MyItems, it is easy to bind against it:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource={Binding MyItems}/>
```

However, I'd like to sort it as well. Using the CollectionViewSource should be the solution but it does not work for me:

```
<ListBox>
 <ListBox.ItemsSource>
  <Binding>
   <Binding.Source>
    <CollectionViewSource Source={Binding MyItems}/>
   </Binding.Source>
  </Binding>
 </ListBox.ItemsSource>
</ListBox>
```

At this point, my ListBox loses its elements.
Am I missing something obvious?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can define the `CollectionViewSource` as a resource and provide your desired sorting...

```
<Window.Resources>
    <CollectionViewSource x:Key="cvs" Source="{Binding MyItems}">
        <CollectionViewSource.SortDescriptions>
            <scm:SortDescription PropertyName="MyItemName" Direction="Ascending"/>
        </CollectionViewSource.SortDescriptions>
    </CollectionViewSource>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource cvs}}"/>
</Grid>
```

The `scm` namespace is `xmlns:scm="clr-namespace:System.ComponentModel;assembly=WindowsBase"`

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. However, my listbox is in a DataTemplate so I can't use a resource. Why does it work as a resource and not as a Source of the Binding?

Comment: Ahh your original answer didn't have the SortDescriptions, so I answered with it, and you edited to include

Answer (score 1):

Create a CollectionViewSource in the CodeBehind which reads from MyItems, and bind your ListBox to that

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding MyCollectionViewSource"} />
```

Comment: -1 OP specifically states they want to avoid C# (code behind)

Comment: Not worthy of a -1.  Sure the OP said that, but future people searching for answers to this might find @Rachel's input valuable.

Comment: @Robaticus Everyone gets bent out of shape on a -1. Since the OP explicitly stated that no C# was to be used; the line has to be drawn somewhere. If the OP did not explicitly call out not wanting to use C# the answer would be fine. Trying to keep the answers relative to the question is all.

Comment: @Aaron I had assumed that the OP didn't want any additional code to do the sorting such as code-behind the View or a Converter. I still think it is a better idea to modify the source of your data to point to a `CollectionViewSource` instead of directly to the List if you are going to be sorting it. It would also allow for other sort options later on if desired.

Comment: I completely agree. I return a CollectionViewSource out of my ViewModel just as you recommended. Explicitly call out the fact that you noted the OP's C# reference in an edit and I can remove the -1. Again this is not saying that you are wrong or incorrect...just slightly off-topic.

Answer (score 0):

Neither of the other answers actually address sorting. They are both right about a `CollectionViewSource`, but you can use that to do the sorting, with `CollectionViewSource.SortDescription`. Taken from [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742542.aspx) and modified:

```
<Window.Resources>

   <src:MyItems x:Key="MyItems"/>

   <CollectionViewSource Source="{StaticResource MyItems}" x:Key="cvs">
     <CollectionViewSource.SortDescriptions>
       <scm:SortDescription PropertyName="CityName"/>
     </CollectionViewSource.SortDescriptions>
   </CollectionViewSource>
</Window.Resources>

<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource cvs}}"
     DisplayMemberPath="CityName" Name="lb">
  <ListBox.GroupStyle>
    <x:Static Member="GroupStyle.Default"/>
  </ListBox.GroupStyle>
</ListBox>
```

In this example,`CityName` would be the property on each item in `MyItems` used to do the sorting

Comment: ummm...my answer does talk about SortDescriptions.

Comment: @Aaron - it didn't when I first loaded the page. You edited to include. Of course, edits within the first few minutes of a post don't show as edits, so I can't prove that.