# How do I do a sum of gridview cells from selected rows in WPF using c#?

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

If I had to do a sum of a specific columns of selected rows in a DataGridView, I would usually do something like

```
decimal total = myDGV.SelectedRows.OfType<DataGridViewRow>()
    .Sum(t => Convert.ToDecimal(t.Cells[2].Value));
```

How do I do that in WPF?

If I did:

```
decimal total = myGrid.SelectedItems.OfType<DataGridRow>()
    .Sum(t => Convert.ToDecimal(t.Cells[2].Value));
```

I get an error `'System.Windows.Controls.DataGridRow' does not contain a definition for 'Cells' and no extension method 'Cells' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Windows.Controls.DataGridRow' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) (CS1061)`

Help please.

Comment: The WPF'ish way would be to use a CollectionSoureSource with SortDescription, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5585277/how-can-i-bind-and-sort-a-collection

Comment: And please ask only one question at a time.

Comment: @KlausGütter I'll keep that in mind. BTW I was looking for a solution in code behind and not in XAML.

Comment: Also this has been answered, e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5549321/how-to-read-value-from-a-cell-from-a-wpf-datagrid/36586256

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not that knowledgeable in LINQ, but this should do the job:

```
List<decimal> targetCells = new List<decimal>();

for (int i = 0; i < myGrid.SelectedItems.Count; i++)
{
    DataRowView row = (DataRowView)myGrid.SelectedItems[i];
    targetCells.Add(Convert.ToDecimal(row[2].ToString()));
}

decimal total = targetCells.Sum();
```

Maybe someone else will show you how to do this in a single LINQ query (if it can be done) :).